# Problem with a plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have a function which has a dependency on x alone. I wanted to find the roots of this equation, so I tried plotting the equation, but I am getting the error "integer expected at position 2 in Surd[0.204286, 4.]". My equation as terms like the fourth root of x. How to solve this issue. My primary objective is to plot this det function. and the secondary objective is to find the roots of this equation using NSolve.

```
P=-0.000487443 x^(3/2) Cosh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7+0.000410809 x^(3/2) Cos[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Cosh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7-3.03769*10^-7 x^2 Cosh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7-0.000487443 x^(3/2) Cosh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7+0.000410809 x^(3/2) Cos[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Cosh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7-3.03769*10^-7 x^2 Cosh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7+0.000487443 x^(3/2) Cos[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7-0.000410809 x^(3/2) Cos[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Cos[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7+3.03769*10^-7 x^2 Cos[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7+0.000487443 x^(3/2) Cos[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7-0.000410809 x^(3/2) Cos[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Cos[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7+3.03769*10^-7 x^2 Cos[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^7-1.21576*10^-8 Sqrt[x] Cos[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Cos[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Cosh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^10-1.21576*10^-8 Sqrt[x] Cos[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Cos[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Cosh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^10-1.21576*10^-8 Sqrt[x] Cos[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Cos[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Cosh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^10-1.21576*10^-8 Sqrt[x] Cos[0.0000792465 Sqrt[x]] Cos[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Cosh[0.0419647 Surd[x, 4.]] Sin[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Sinh[0.0839293 Surd[x, 4.]] Surd[x, 4.]^10;
Plot[P, {x, 0, 10000}]
```

Comment: As stated by the error message, the second argument of `Surd[]` should be an `Integer`, i.e., you need to replace `Surd[x, 4.]` with `Surd[x, 4]`.

Comment: I did define like this in my input , it is like Surd[expression,4]. I dont know why in determinant it is coming like Surd[expression,4.]

Comment: If that's the case, then you can do this: `Q = P/.Surd[m_, n_]:>Surd[m, Round[n]]`, and then `Plot[]` Q.

Comment: It works, thanks.